# Problem with area calculation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, area

I encountered a problem in QGIS 2.10.1 when I tried to calculate the areas of polygons in a polygon layer.

I followed the instructions here (http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html) to save the layer as one with selected CRS UTM zone 33S. It saved successfully; however, for some reason the saved layer with the new CRS won't show up on the map. Moreover, when I went to field calculator to try to calculate the area, it simply shows "nan" as results.

I have calculated areas in the same way before, and never encountered such problem. It seems that saving the original layer with UTM zone 33S causes the problem (since the saved layer won't even show up on the map). Any thought why this happened and how should I fix it?

Below is the link to the shapefile so that you can play with it to see the problem.
[shapefile](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4904426/shapefile1.zip)

Comment: I attached a link to the shapefile in the original post so that you can play with it. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: I noticed that 33S is for South Africa, while in this case I need to reproject it to the CRS of another country. Then everything works.